# how to see a http reponse message using telnet command?

Tags: http, telnet

I am trying to telnet to different web servers and see what http response messages I get. I've tried `telnet some_host_name 80`, and then the shell says `connected to some_host_name escape character is '^]'`. How exactly do I get the http response message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After telnet connects type: `GET /`

```
telnet stackoverflow.com 80      
Trying 104.16.36.249...
Connected to stackoverflow.com.                                                                                                                               
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

You can also use `curl` utility.